# how to match part of a string using regexp

Tags: pattern-matching, tcl

Hi I want to match only a part of a variable and store it. For example for the element **b12asc34sx110** I want to match **b12asc34s** and store it in a variable and also store **x110** in another variable. The value of the element keep changing, like it can be b12hdh56sx120 or b12hdgwa78x20. The code which I am trying is

```
set element b12asc34sx110
regexp [\(.*)\ {[^x(0-9]}] $element matched1 
regexp [x(0-9)] $element matched2
puts $matched1
puts $matched2
```

The value of element will come from the user hence it may change everytim. 
I am new to regexp hence finding it difficult. I am not getting the output for it. Please help me with this.

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @abiessu: it is tcl as you can see in the tag.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I see that now, thank you.  I was expecting that part of the question to be specified directly in the question, but I will observe the tags in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set element "b12asc34sx110"
set pattern "(.*)(x.*$)"

if {[regexp $pattern $element whmatch sub1 sub2]} {
    puts $sub1 
    puts $sub2
}
```

Notice:
 if you have a several x in your string, the second capture group will begin at the last x, since the first quantifier is evaluated first and is greedy (default behavior), thus the first capturing group contains the largest possible substring. 
If your are looking for the smallest first substring, use this pattern instead (with a lazy quantifier):

```
set pattern "(.*?)(x.*$)"
```

Comment: It's strongly advisable to put regular expressions in `{` curly braces `}` with Tcl so as to avoid myriad problems.

Comment: @DonalFellows: like that: `set pattern {(.*)(x.*$)}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "x" can't occur in the second part:

```
set element "b12asc34sx110"
if {[set i [string last "x" $element]] >= 0} {
  set head [string range $element 0 $i-1]
  set tail [string range $element $i end]
}
```

If "x" can occur in the second part but not in the first, change `string last` to `string first`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp like `regexp {([^x]*)x([0-9]*)} "b12asc23sx110" matched1 sub1 sub2`.

Comment: If I am using      regexp (\.*\)[(^x*)] $ele matched
to match the first part I am getting an error saying Error: unknown command '^x*' (CMD-005)
and if I do      regexp {(\.*\)[(^x*)]}  $ele matched it is showing unbalanced paranthesis

Comment: The regexp I posted is `[^x]*` (the character class of all characters except x, with * to catch as many as possible) which is captured by `\(` and `\)` surrounding it, followed by a literal "x", followed by `[0-9]` the character class of digits, also set to be captured.  You should use two match variables at the end to catch the results.  The other answer using a split is also very good given the limits you have placed on the value you are decoding.

Comment: I tried this **regexp {\([^x]*\)x\([0-9]*\)} $ele matched1 matched2** but I am getting a 0 as no char is getting matched. DO u have a suggestion? @abiessu

Answer (score 0):

If the "x" is a constant then all you have to do is split at the x and put the first value in one and the second in another - regardless of what is in each side that changes but only if the "x" is a constant and will always appear. To get alpha and numeric since we don't have enough data to know if it will always be numeric on the right a lazy rule like `(*)x(*)` should grab everything on the left of the x (assuming this is always present) and everything on the right.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte is right, my rule assumes that no other x will appear except for the middle samples you gave, if more appears, his would be more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps, but since the context is unknow, your way can be better.

Comment: If I try     regexp {\([^x]*\)x\([0-9]*\)} $element matched1 matched2 the output is coming 0 and also for     regexp {\(.*\)x\(.*\)} $element matched1 matched2 the result is zero

Comment: Did you try mine just for the heck of it and see what result you got? Maybe in this case the lazier/greedier method works better?